# Activity as ProgressDialog

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]I have a requirement of having a activity as dialog (Not an Alert dialog, instead a progress dialog). There are no ui components in this activity since this activity does server interaction, based on server response next activities are started. Only a progress dialog with cancel button needs to be shown in this activity. Now the problem is when ever this activity is launched just before progress dialog is displayed a small black rectanagle is visible for a second or more, also when this activity is finished this is visible. How to get rid of this ? or is there any better way of haveing a progress dialog as activity ?
-Thanks & regards,
Manju

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActivityAsDialogActivity.this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String str ="Hellow World";

    txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtview);
    this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
    txtView.setText(R.string.select_dialog);

    ActivityAsDialogActivity.this.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

    mProgressHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            if (mProgress >= MAX_PROGRESS) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityAsDialogActivity.this, ActivityOne.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                mProgress++;
                mProgressDialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
                mProgressHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 100);
            }
        }
    };//end of handler

    showDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
    mProgressHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

}//end of onCreate()

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Log.d("Manju ==>"," back key pressed");
    finish();
}

@Override
public void finish(){
    Log.d("Manju ==>", " inside finish()");
    super.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Creating Global Dialog](http://sherifandroid.blogspot.com/2011/08/creating-global-dialogs.html), I used a transparent activity with a dialog inside. I think you can do the same thing. I do not recall facing the problem you are facing, and it worked perfectly.

[Check it out](http://sherifandroid.blogspot.com/2011/08/creating-global-dialogs.html)

Comment: Hi Sherif, I tried making activity as tranparent by changing the theme as in your example but stil i see a small white/transparent rectangle which lasts for less than a second

Comment: @Manju then there is a problem in your code... show us your onCreate

Comment: @Manju according to my tutorial u do not setContentView in the activity. You only showDialog